# Avoiding duplicate lines on file

Tags: php, duplicates, line

I want to avoid duplicate lines on file:

```
file_put_contents('ips.txt', $ip . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

I want to put 1 ip only once using file_put. `fwrite` does not work on the server's PHP version correctly.

**Code**

```
file_put_contents('ips.txt', $ip . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

`fwrite` code doesn't work with my version of PHP.

```
$file = fopen("ips.txt", "w");
echo fwrite($file, $ip);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Get the ips first and check if the ip is already in the file

Comment: wouldent a database make this so much easier?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to retrieve all lines of your file:

```
$lines = file('ips.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

`$lines` is an array containing all lines of your file. `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flags are used to skip empty lines and to ignore line endings.

After that, you need to know if your address is already in this array and insert your IP if it is not:

```
if (!in_array($ip, $lines)) {
    file_put_contents('ips.txt', $ip . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

[PHP file() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

[PHP in_array() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)